# Version error when installing docker toolbox on OSX

Tags: macos, docker, package, devops, docker-toolbox

I'm new to docker and have been following the guide, trying to install the toolbox version v1.10.0-rc1. All seems to have gone well until I try the hello-world example and then I get:

> Error response from daemon: client is newer than server (client API
>   version: 1.22, server API version: 1.21)

I see there is much online about similar errors, however all attempts so far have failed, and being unfamiliar with docker, the suggested solutions are somewhat cryptic.

Has any had a similar issue and found a solution?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you try a `docker-machine upgrade <machine-name>`?

Comment: At this point I've reverted to use the toolbox version 1.9.1i as this is what is available from the main site. I shall revisit this question when the main site is updated to use v1.10.

Comment: @VonC I have the same issue, but with 1.10.0-rc4, and that doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: @fredrik OK. I believe 1.10 final just got released. An hour ago.

Comment: @VonC Where do you see that? Here are the releases: https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases

Comment: @fredrik https://github.com/docker/docker/releases And forget toolbox. All you need is VirtualBox and docker-machine.exe copied from https://github.com/docker/machine/releases

Answer (score 0):

Docker tool box is being used in old mac and or windows system.
today there are differnt approaches to install docker on your mac.
In case your mac isn't that old try install it from [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/)